# How to tell g++ to use stuff from .lib file?

Tags: c++, linux, g++, lib

I am trying to compile a C++ using g++ in Linux which uses some functions defined in a header file crated by someone. I am not much experienced with C++ so I am not sure how to proceed (or even if I understand what should be done).

I have all these files in a single directory:

- `PaLaser.cxx`, this is the main.
- `USBM3.h`
- [`hidapi.h`](https://github.com/signal11/hidapi/blob/master/hidapi/hidapi.h)
- `hidapi.lib`
- `hidapi.dll`
- `USBM3.lib`
- `USBM3.dll`

This was created by someone for Windows and now I want to compile for Linux. The `USBM3.h` looks like this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class HIDDLL
    { 
    private:
        static void init();
        static void SendDataToUSB();
        static   int parseChar(unsigned char );
        static   void ParseByte(string);
        static   int openFile(char *);
        static   void SendFile();   
        static  void readADC(); 
        
    public:

         /* This method is used to generate sequence  */
        static __attribute__((visibility("default"))) void  seqMODE(int mode);

        /* This method is used to turn off LASER */
        static __attribute__((visibility("default"))) void  LASERTurnOff(void);

         /* This method is used to send freq data to ARM   */ 
        static __attribute__((visibility("default"))) void  sendFreq(int freq);

        bla bla bla

    };
```

and in the `PaLaser.cxx` there is this:

```
#include "hidapi.h"
#include "USBM3.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "USBM3.lib")
```

When I run

```
g++ PaLaser.cxx -o PaLaser
```

I get

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccUXpAbN.o: in function `main':
PaLaser.cxx:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `HIDDLL::isDeviceAttached()'
/usr/bin/ld: PaLaser.cxx:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `HIDDLL::readLASERstate()'
.............
```

where `...........` stands for all the things defined in `USBM3.h`.

I have no certainty whether these things are packed within the `USBM3.lib` file, but I hope they are. How do I tell g++ to look there?

Comment: .lib and .dll files are usually WIndows-specific and can not be used on linux at all.

Comment: Oh, I thought that dll was for Windows and .lib for Linux...

Comment: No `.so` and `.a` files are for linux. `.dll` and `.lib` are windows.

Comment: .lib is a static or export library usually produced and consumed by Microsoft Visual C++ linker.

Comment: So basically I need the `hidapi.so` and `USBM3.so` or the source to generate them?

Comment: Basically yes, you need hidapi.so and USBM3.so or the source code to compile them.

Comment: Build instructions are in the Readme.txt file: [https://github.com/signal11/hidapi/blob/master/README.txt#L209](https://github.com/signal11/hidapi/blob/master/README.txt#L209)

Comment: Thanks. `hidapi.h` and related stuff is something standard that I think I have already successfully installed in the PC, so I will try to get this `USBM3.so` or `USBM3.source` which contains specific functions. Thank you for your comments. If you want to put them as answer I can accept it.